# httpful sending image by rest

Tags: php, json, rest

I need to know how to get an image in the RESTful webservice using [HTTPFUL](http://phphttpclient.com/)

library by PHP. I know I should GET it by JSON and decode, but don't know how and I cannot find any examples of it in google.

Comment: So you are trying to use an API that uses JSON to deliver data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a *short* example of what the response for such a `GET` would look like.

Answer (score 0):

I have been managed with my problem. I saved response from the server into the file. This is a little bit code, if this could be helpful for someone.

```
$url = Camera::$HOST . Image::$URI . '/' . Camera::$cameralist[$i]['cameraId'];
        $request = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
                ->send();
        $path = 'image_' . Camera::$cameralist[$i]['cameraId'] . '.jpeg';
        $this->setPath($path);
        $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $request);
        fclose($fp);
```